# Equivalent of Guice's MapBinder for Guava Table

Tags: java, guava, guice

For a normal `Map`, you can setup binding in Guice like this

```
MapBinder<K, V> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(), K.class, V.class);
mapBinder.addBinding(key).to(V.class);
```

Is there an equivalent setup binding for [Guava table](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Table.html)?

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there was.

Comment: so I can have a `@Provides` method that returns a `Table<K1, K2, V>`, but I don't want to instantiate different object of type V. I want to rely on Guice to do DI and create objects when needed. What's the best way to do it with Table?

Comment: Do it with a map with pairs of keys, then convert that map to a `Table`.